# Linq - Joining through a dictionary where the KeyValuePair.Value is a collection itself

Tags: c#, linq, join, dictionary

trying to get my head round what the joins should look like for the example below. Any help determining if it is possible to write linq for the following would be greatly apprieciated!

```
        List<string> col1;
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> join2;
```

I wish to select all keys from the dictionary where the items in col1 exist in the Value List collection of the dictionary.

```
        IEnumerable<string> query = from c1 in col1
                                    join kvp in join2 on c1 equals kvp.Value
                                    where c1 == "foo"
                                    orderby kvp.Key
                                    select kvp.Key;
```

Obviously the above fails as kvp.Value is a List and not a string to equate to c1 - any pointers?

Comment: Where *all* of the items in col1 appear in the value? Where *any* of the items in col1 appear in the value? Is order important? Where does "foo" come in? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve at the moment. Please give some sample data.

Comment: Hey Jon, I wanted to link through a collection in the Value property of a KeyValuePair to return a Key. The conditional 'foo' part denotes the value I wish to find in a value collection to return the key. I am after _Any_ matches - so the multiple from clauses and a where condition using a contains matches my requirements. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Using an Any call would have worked too...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the join is needed... if you are select on "foo" then the following would yield the same result:

```
        IEnumerable<string> query = from kvp in join2
                                where kvp.Value.Contains ("foo")
                                orderby kvp.Key
                                select kvp.Key;
```

Alternatively with the join

```
        IEnumerable<string> query = from c1 in col1 where c1 == "foo" from kvp in join2 
                                where kvp.Value.Contains (c1) 
                                orderby kvp.Key
                                select kvp.Key;
```

Comment: Thanks - that is what I wanted - it was a boiled down to a simple example, the real complex reason makes more sense in my business case. Didn't realise multiple froms were possible, makes perfect sense now. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
from kvp in dict
from e in kvp.Value
... // join on e here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from c1 in col1.Keys
             from c2 in col1.Values
             where c1 == c2
             select c1;
```